# Можно ли группе www-data давать права на запись в директорию сайта?

Tags: linux, wordpress, веб-программирование, nginx, веб-сервер

Есть сайт на wordpress, в который нужно удаленно вносить изменения. Права на запись имеет пользователь www—data. Я добавил своего пользователя developer в группу www—data и дал этой группе права на запись в директорию сайта. Правильно ли это с точки зрения безопасности? Если нет, то как лучше организовать удаленное редактирование сайта?

Comment: Правильно девать права php = юзеру, а не наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

На практике, есть только реально один работающий способ безопасно настроить права в LEMP стэке. И как правильно указал @SeVlad - правильно давать права php юзеру и должен быть отдельный php юзер (никак не `www-data`) даже если речь идет об одном сайте - это нисколько не извиняет того чтобы не делать правильно.

Как правильно расписано [здесь](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-and-php-fpm-what-my-permissions-should-be), а именно:

- Создайте отдельного пользователя конкретно под ваш сайт если таковой еще не существует. Именуйте его как короткое название сайта без доменной части, или по назначению или типу CMS например `magento`, и тд
- Сконфигурирейте PHP-FPM таким образом чтобы пул для этого сайта исполнялся под этим самым пользователем
- Поставьте права на все файлы и папки сайта так `chown -R example:example /path/to/website/files`
- Добавьте пользователя веб-сервера в группу пользователя сайта: `usermod -a -G example www-data`
- Выставьте разрешения таким образом чтобы пользователи группы (а это веб-сервер) смогут читать файлы сайта (а выполнять их или писать им и не надо)

  ```
    chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o= /path/to/website/files
  ```

C дефолтным значением umask для обычных пользователей - новые папки и файлы создаваемые пользователем вручную либо через исполнение скриптов - будут читабельными вебсервером.

Безопасно. Нет проблем.

Бонусом что можно легко запретить веб доступ к чувствительным файлам не только через конфиг вебсервера но и просто убрав разрешения для группы:

```
chmod 0600 some-config.php
chmod g-r some-config.php
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118700/discussion-on-answer-by-danila-vershinin----www-data---).

Answer (score -1):

Права на запись у процесса php быть должны в обязательном порядке, иначе много функционала перестанет работать - обновление плагинов, кеширование страниц и скриптов и т.д.

Если php выполняется под пользователем `www-data`, значит, у этого пользователя должны быть права 644 на файлы и 755 на папки.

Если вы добавили в группу `www-data` своего пользователя и хотите, чтобы он писал по ftp файлы в папки сайта, то надо дать на все файлы права 664, а на папки - 775. Это позволит избежать ошибок выполнения, указанных выше.

Comment: И любого чужого сайта можно будет записать и выполнить шелл :)

Comment: Вот что ты несёшь, а? Во-первых, если у любого соседнего сайта php юзер тот же, `www-data`, то он успешно выполнит любые действия на обсуждаемом сайте, даже при 664/755. Во-вторых, у ТС ни слова о соседних сайтах.

Comment: Вот я несу то, что ты сказал в "во-первых". Подумай и сложи 2+2. А во вторых - вне зависимости от этого сервер нужно настраивать безопасно и не давать www-data доступа в юзеровские каталоги.

Comment: @SeVlad в какие юзеровские каталоги,  о чём вообще речь? php выполняется под www-data. Какие ему права давать, ответь. Можешь сразу в Кодекс глянуть.

Comment: Каталог юзера - это домашний каталог юзера. В котором  находится условный "www". в котором находится каталог сайта. Кроме www там могут быть и др каталоги с юзеровскими настройками, файлами и тд. Вот напр https://i.imgur.com/9fWNm5W.jpg

Comment: @SeVlad ну это ты так делаешь. А сплошь и рядом сайты кладут в /var/www. И ответь, наконец, на вопрос. Если php юзер = www-data (по умолчанию в Apache, Ubuntu),то какие права ставить на папки и файлы и кто их владелец

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118688/discussion-between-sevlad-and-kagg-design).